# Why do we connect neutral and ground at the transformer?

Tags: grounding, wiring, electricity, neutral

Why do we connect neutral to ground at the transformer, why can't we just connect that neutral to the ground at our house?

Comment: It depends on your local regulations, and we don't know your location. In some locations the neutral is earthed at the house. Please edit your location so we can answer that.

Comment: I live in India

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a neutral wire add any protection from near-by lightning strike](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/367295/how-does-a-neutral-wire-add-any-protection-from-near-by-lightning-strike)

Comment: You've asked 8 questions now and maybe this is a good time to remind you of what is expected by most site users. Answers that are useful to you, as a mark of courtesy, are normally up-voted by the person asking the question. The answer that best fulfills the question is normally formally accepted as [per this method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png). Questions that don't answer or are confusing can be remedied by leaving a comment asking for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

A grounded neutral ensures that line-to-ground voltage is the lower phase voltage (240V~ in India). Without a grounded neutral, in the event of an earth fault on one of the lines, the line-to-earth voltage would be the higher line voltage (415V~ in India).

A grounded neutral enables safety tripping during a line-to-earth fault. In the event of failure of the tripping mechanism during a line-to-earth fault, a grounded neutral would ensure that a person coming in contact with either of the other lines would be exposed to phase voltage only and not line voltage.

The electrical utility supplier alone can guarantee effectiveness of the safety mechanisms by grounding the neutral at the distribution transformer.

Grounding the neutral would not be in the consumer's scope unless mandated by local regulations. (In India, consumers are not permitted to ground the neutral).

Comment: Do the meters in India contain a RCD?

Comment: Hi Ian,  Regulations mandate provision of  a RCD on the distribution board. The meters do not contain one.

Comment: Who owns and maintains the distribution board?

Comment: The consumer, Ian.

Comment: Thanks, some parts of the third world has a nice system when the meter contains the RCD etc and the consumer plugs in their wiring to the meter, hence making it much safer.    (It is to even much such a system check for a broken N.)

Comment: Anytime, and yes, that's a real safe system, Ian.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, because the national electric code says it must be done like that.

India mainly uses the TN-S electrical system, which does connect the PE and N at the transformer. PE is also connected to earth ground potential with an electrode at the transformer. All the return currents flow in the Neutral, and in normal use, there will be no current in the PE, so it equalizes the potential between transformer and house.

And since PE is provided to house, there is no need for local ground electrode.